# how to Hyberlink many cells with pdf files automaticly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Is there any method to hyberlink a large amount of pdf files into excel column without repeating (hyberlink for just one file) manually for each cell ?

Comment: You could do it using VBA. It's not simple if you have little to no experience with VBA. If you have just try and return only when you bump into a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the attachment to see if this is what you want.

Put all pdf files in a file folder, Crtl+A to select them, press **Shift** then right click, choose **Copy as path**.
[image]